# Why my GPU piece of code run much slower then cpu

Tags: python, gpu, pycuda

This is one of the standard example code we find every where...

```
import time
import numpy

import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.cumath as cumath
import pycuda.autoinit

size = 1e7

t0 = time.time()
x = numpy.linspace(1, size, size).astype(numpy.float32)
y = numpy.sin(x)
t1 = time.time()

cpuTime = t1-t0
print(cpuTime)

t0 = time.time()
x_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(x)
y_gpu = cumath.sin(x_gpu)
y = y_gpu.get()
t1 = time.time()

gpuTime = t1-t0
print(gpuTime)
```

the results are:  200 msec for cpu and 2.45 sec for GPU... more then 10X

I'm running on  win 10... vs 2015 with PTVS...

Best regards...

Steph

Comment: For a start, you should probably use `timeit` to accurately time average code execution time. Secondly, it is possible that there is a lot of overhead in the `gpuarray.to_gpu(x)` call. Try doing this set-up outside of your timing function. Finally, bear in mind that numpy is highly optimised for these sorts of operations. So it is not unreasonable to see a poorer performance on a GPU in some instances, without optimisation of the GPU code as well.

Comment: I've run the above code using the `timeit` module. I get 20.6ms per loop (100 loops) for the gpu code and 129ms per loop for numpy cpu code. GPU=GTX760, CPU=i5-2400. Interestingly, the gpu code seems to run slower the first time it is run in an interactive python prompt (400ms), but faster (20ms) with repeated executions in the same instance.

Comment: Thank you... yes I see the same... quite an overhead... for the first pass...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `pycuda` introduces some additional overhead the first time you call the `cumath.sin()` function (~400ms on my system). I suspect this is due to the need to compile CUDA code for the function being called. More importantly, this overhead is independent of the size of the array being passed to the function. Additional calls to `cumath.sin()` are much faster, with CUDA code already compiled for use. On my system, the gpu code given in the question runs in about 20ms (for repeated runs), compared to roughly 130ms for the numpy code.

I don't profess to know much at all about the inner workings of `pycuda`, so would be interested to hear other people's opinions on this.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer... Yes it seem to have a quite of overhead...